# can any body tell me how to make this complex object?

Tags: modeling

This is the model and i made it 
https://in.pinterest.com/pin/757730706026954368/

I tried it but not up to the mark 
[image]

Comment: could you please display it here? because not everyone has access to pinterest. Are you talking about this one? https://i.pinimg.com/474x/7d/32/17/7d32174bb19ad249f19d12e394ea9d4b.jpg   and if so, why using sculpting?

Comment: YES thats a model , i used torus and cylinder and sculpting join the with sculpting !

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to work this one with sculpting but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: sad that the question has been closed (why that?), I wanted to submit an answer

Comment: @moon I cast the downvote, when there was no reference image (before the edit). I think it is still not quite clear, what the problem with the current model is, compared to the blueprint. However, I cast a reopen vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image gives you quite a good blueprint and the first tip is to start with the big forms and then make the details.

Load the blueprint into blender and start modelling with a mirror modifier to model only half of it.

Start with a Torus and make the bulg on top with a uv sphere that you scaled in x and y to get the desired angle. Connect the two with a boolean -> Union and go on with the other parts in the same way.

For the extrusion part try to model it from the buleprint with single verts and then connect it with the torus to bevel the single verts for a smooth transition.

Comment: i tried it but didnt get smooth transition , it look like there is a gap between torus and cylinder